# Bajar CSV de Drive sin Poder Usar Excel

Tags: csv

Necesito bajar dos CSV de un mail que he recibido que me pasa los links en drive.

El tema es que son más largos que un Excel (más de 1 millón de filas, una sola columna), y gmail por defecto me los baja en Excel. Son para una prueba para un trabajo.

Necesitaría hacerlo de la forma más sencilla (luego necesitaría quitar duplicados etc. con lo que tendría que ser una herramienta que permitise ciertos cálculos).

Qué me sugerís que haga? (básicamente pregunto cómo hacerlo sin Excel y que me permita calcular).

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Bájalo en CSV: Archivo -> Descargar como -> CSV.

Luego te haces un script de Python (o algún lenguaje de programación similar con el que estés familiarizado) y ahí puedes buscar y eliminar duplicados. Python tiene un módulo para leer y manejar CSV integrado: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html si sabes manejar Python, yo creo que es lo más sencillo.

Si no, tendrías que hacer la operación directamente en Google Drive. En otra hoja haces que te copie los valores no duplicados de la hoja original, y luego descargas la hoja nueva.

Otras opción más manual:

1. Te copias las x primeras filas de la hoja, a otra hoja de cálculo (en Drive o Excel, lo que quieras).
2. Filtras ahí lo que no quieras.
3. Copias las siguientes x filas de la hoja, a tu hoja de copia.
4. Repite pasos 2 y 3 hasta acabar.

Eso sí, esto no tiene nada que ver con programar, excepto se trata de un algoritmo.